# json encode multidimensional array get value

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sysid] => 1
            [code] => 140101000
            [name] => China
            [parentid] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sysid] => 2
            [code] => 140102000
            [name] => Japan
            [parentid] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sysid] => 3
            [code] => 140103000
            [name] => Hongkong
            [parentid] => 1
        )
)
```

This is my array that i get from my print_r request it is from php it is a multidimensional array that i used `json_encode` now this is the data i get from success. I want to get all the value of sysid and name from this json to be put in select option how is this possible

I used this code below but i get undefined and i get 4,000 result

```
PAIR 0: undefined

PAIR 0: undefined

PAIR 1: undefined

PAIR 1: undefined

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].sysid);
    console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].name);
}
```

`UPDATE`

my bad the first one is the print_r this is the json

```
[{"sysid":"1","code":"140101000","name":"China","parentid":"1"},{"sysid":"2","code":"140102000","name":"Japan","parentid":"1"},
{"sysid":"3","code":"140103000","name":"Hongkong","parentid":"1"}]
```

ajax is

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../include/country.php',
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // the next thing you want to do 
        var obj = data;
        console.log(obj);
        //for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        //console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].sysid);
        //console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].name);
        //}


    }
});
```

Comment: show us the ajax request code, please.

Comment: your code should work.. i am not seeing any errors..

Comment: in my console.log i get Pair 0: undefined how is that ok sir @MrBearAndBeer but in regular console log if the console log is only `console.log(data);` i get result what i want to show in console log is only the `sysid` and `name`

Comment: you should use the obj.length, and not the data.length

Comment: Am I right that you want to put the results into a **select** input? That's what I feel like you're asking

Comment: @thedouglenz yes it is what i want to do in success and in order for me to do i need to get the data from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../include/country.php',
    dataType : "json",
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
       for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].sysid);
           console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].name);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is showing us the PHP code, not the returned JSON.

Comment: why? just delete the var obj = data, or update your loop to use obj instead data.

Comment: i did try to just use the json alone i mean i copied it it worked but when i use data it is undefined what seems to be the problem?

Comment: also i noticed that the first item it has no json equivalent it has a result for print_r but for json none it is blank..

Comment: why u are using the POST method, if you want GET the data, and not pass?

Comment: when i use the copied thing json `[{"sysid":"1","code":...` i do it like this `var obj = [{"sysid":"1","code":...` it is working it has result but when i do `var obj= data;` the result is undefined

Comment: you mean it ajax my type should be GET? let me try it

Comment: this is hopeless i still get undefined for all `console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].sysid);
        console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].name);` but for `console.log(data)` i get result i dont know why this is happening the `sysid ` and `name` are all correct why do i get undefined this is beyond hope

Comment: yes i did copied the entire thing then create new console.log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69008/discussion-between-mrbearandbeer-and-hogrider).