# json not value but print_r has value php pdo jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, pdo

```
if (isset($_POST['continentid'])) {
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM country_tbl WHERE parent_id = ? ");
      $stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['continentid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $country[] = array('sysid' => $selected_row['sys_id'],'name' => $selected_row['countryname']);
            } 
            //print_r($country);
            echo json_encode($country);
            //echo "312321321321";
            //return $country;

        }
    }
}


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../include/country.php',
    dataType : "json",
    data: {
        continentid: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
       for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].sysid);
           console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[i].name);
       }
    }
});
```

I have this code above that send request using jquery ajax it will return an id that will be used as parameter for select statement. I then use these values on select option box. I have posted a question for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995952/json-encode-multidimensional-array-get-value). It is working ok now the odd thing is the first value on continent does not give the list of country if using json but when i use print_r it is giving me the list of countries but for the other continent json value is ok i am getting value for  country. Question is why does the first value on the list does not give json value but if print_r it has value what is wrong in this setting?

`Update`

If i do

print_r($country);
echo json_encode($country);

for first element

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sysid] => 1
            [code] => 140101000
            [name] => China
            [parentid] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sysid] => 2
            [code] => 140102000
            [name] => Japan
            [parentid] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sysid] => 3
            [code] => 140103000
            [name] => Hongkong
            [parentid] => 1
        )
)
```

If i do

print_r($country);
echo json_encode($country);

for second element

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sysid] => 1
            [code] => 140101000
            [name] => China
            [parentid] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sysid] => 2
            [code] => 140102000
            [name] => Japan
            [parentid] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sysid] => 3
            [code] => 140103000
            [name] => Hongkong
            [parentid] => 1
        )
)


[
{"sysid":"1","code":"140101000","name":"China","parentid":"1"},{"sysid":"2","code":"140102000","name":"Japan","parentid":"1"},{"sysid":"3","code":"140103000","name":"Hongkong","parentid":"1"}
]
```

`UPDATE`

I think i found the problem although i havent found a solution yet i think the character `ñ` and `'`  is the reason why they wont return a value for json any idea on how to make it return these values?

Comment: share your json structure please.

Comment: something like above...for example that one is list of continent the first one wont return value but if print_r i will return value

Comment: use `json_encode` on  *country.php* and share the output with question

Comment: if there is a diff between `print_r ` and your `json`, please add both in the question. so it would be easy for others to identify the problem

Comment: the difference is when i do print_r i get an output in ajax success but on json none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line `$dbh->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");` to my config file fixed the problem so it really has something to do with special characters like `ñ` json_encode with return null value if there are special characters

Answer (score 0):

try it. `JSON.parse(data)` convert string to json.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../include/country.php',
    dataType : "json",
    data: {
        continentid: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
  data=  JSON.parse(data);
      data.each(key,value)  {

           console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[key].sysid);
           console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[key].name);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: use (each loop ) function instead of ( for loop)

Comment: sorry i didnt see that

Comment: data.each(key,value)  {

           console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[key].sysid);
           console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + data[key].name);
       }
use this instead of (forloop )

Comment: data.each(key,value)  { unexpected token { when i remove it i get unexpected token A

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
success: function(data) {
   $(data).each(function(i,v){
       console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + v.sysid);
       console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + v.name);
   });
}
```

```js
var data = [{
  "sysid": "1",
  "code": "140101000",
  "name": "China",
  "parentid": "1"
}, {
  "sysid": "2",
  "code": "140102000",
  "name": "Japan",
  "parentid": "1"
}, {
  "sysid": "3",
  "code": "140103000",
  "name": "Hongkong",
  "parentid": "1"
}];
$(data).each(function(i, v) {
  console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + v.sysid);
  console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + v.name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Change the piece of php code like,

```
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
     $country=array();// initialise $country first
     while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         $country[] = array('sysid' => $selected_row['sys_id'],'name' => $selected_row['countryname']);
     } 
     echo json_encode($country);
 }
```

Comment: same result sir no console.log for json but there is for print_r for first element but on second element all is there

Comment: Remove the `print_r($country)` from your php code. Only there should be `echo json_encode()`; As you are using `dataType : "json",`. And the response must be in json format

Comment: i remove print_r same thing no console.log for first for second there is

Comment: do i need to change other as i can see you only add initialize right?i add initialize then your code same thing why is this happening?

Comment: @HogRider Can you show me your online demo for the same. If not, then it seems difficult to point out the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69174/discussion-between-hogrider-and-rohan-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../include/country.php',
    dataType : "json",
    data: {
        continentid: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
  data=  JSON.parse(data);
      data.each(key,value)  {

           console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + value.sysid);
           console.log("PAIR " + i + ": " + value.name);
       }
    }
});
```